# HowTo write a QML-Keyboard with return value

Tags: keyboard, qml, virtual

I'm using lot's of TextInputs within ListViews in my QML-Application. To modify the value I'm providing a virtual QML-Keyboard, that also contains a TextInput.

When I click on a TextInput in the ListView, the TextInput within the QML-Keyboard get's focus and the user can start editing. When finished the text should be sent to the TextInput within the ListView.

The problem I have is, that I don't know how to copy the text of the keyboard's TextInput to the ListView's-TextInput because the focus is lost when starting my virtual keyboard.

Comment: Store `id` of `TextInput` was clicked in `onClicked` or some else event. And after text was entered in the keyboard set this text to stored input element

Comment: @folibis The problem is, that the TextInput is defined within a delegate. That's why it is not possible to access the TextInput by id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each delegate item in a `ListView` is univocally identified by its `index` attached property. The first delegate in the list has index 0, then 1 and so on.

A `ListView` has a property `currentIndex` referring to the currently selected item delegate. When the `currentIndex` is set to a specific delegate also the `currentItem` property is set to the corresponding delegate object.

Given these properties, you can exploit them to obtain the desired behaviour. When you select a `TextInput` to edit it, you can set the `currentIndex` of the list to the index of the `TextInput` delegate. In this way also `currentItem` is set and it can later be used to refer the delegate (and the `TextInput` inside) when the editing in the virtual keyboard is finished.

Here is an example that better explains my point:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Window {
    width: 200
    height: 300

    visible: true

    Component {
        id: myDelegate
        Rectangle {
            width: myList.width; height: 20
            color: myList.currentIndex === index ? "lightgreen" : "lightgray"  // distinguish the selecte delegate 
            onFocusChanged: textInput.forceActiveFocus()
            property alias textInput: textInput     // alias the textInput   // (1)

            TextInput  {
                id: textInput
                anchors.fill: parent

                onCursorVisibleChanged: {
                    if(cursorVisible)
                    {
                        myList.currentIndex = index   // (2)
                        keyboardInput.text = textInput.getText(0, textInput.text.length) // (3)
                        keyboardInput.forceActiveFocus()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        ListView {
            id: myList
            model: 5
            delegate: myDelegate
            spacing: 10
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
        }

        Rectangle {
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignBottom
            color: "steelblue"
            Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width
            Layout.preferredHeight: 40
            TextInput  {
                anchors.centerIn: parent          // simulate the keyboard
                id: keyboardInput
                width: parent.width
                font.pixelSize: parent.height
                onEditingFinished: {
                    myList.currentItem.textInput.text = getText(0, text.length)   //(4)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a simplified example in which your virtual keyboard is substituted by a blue `TextInput` with id `keyboardInput`. Each time a `TextInput` in the list is focused, the focus is passed to `keyboardInput` for editing text.

First of all the `TextInput` in the delegate is aliased (1) to be accessible from outside the delegate. When a `TextInput` in the list get focused for editing (in my case I consider the `CursorVisibleChanged` event), the list `currentIndex` is set to the `index` of the delegate (2) and also the current text in the `TextInput` is copied inside `keyboardInput` (3). When the editing is finished, the text inside `keyboardInput` is copied back to the currently selected `TextInput` via `currentitem` (4).

This approach applies even with more than one `ListView`: simply store the current list in a variable at an higher scope and refer that variable in (4) to set the text in the correct delegate.

Comment: Your approach works really well. One of my problems is, that I'm having multiple TextInputs per ListView. To realize this I have to use multiple indexes (1st ListView, 2nd currentIndex and 3rd TextInput within the delegate). This is really complicated to handle, just to realize a keyboard. At this moment I'm trying to implement the virtual keyboard within a new Window. That way I don't have to store ID's because I won't change the focus of the selected TextInput.

Comment: `currentIndex` must not be stored as it refers to a specific list, i.e. when you have the `ListView` id you can write `list_id.currentIndex`. Its the `ListView` id which shuold be stored. For what concerns the multiple `TextInput`, you can reassign the alias in the delegate. In a totally different approach, passing the `id` of the `TextInput` to a function would be easier/better, probably.

Comment: 1. What do you mean with "reassign the alias in delegate"? 2. Passing the ID would be good, but you can't access a TextInput inside a delegate by a function that is defined outside the delegate. Therefore I would have to Create a new virtual keyboard within every delegate.

Comment: 1) Uhm, nevermind I was wrong! Sorry. :/ However you can use a property instead of an alias and assign (and reassign) it as a specific `TextInput` is selected. 2) you can pass the id (e.g. `textInput` in my example) and call in an external javascript function something like `localVariableName.text = textToBeSet`. If you want I can try to modify this example to consider your specific use case.

Comment: I already implemented a Keyboard within a new Window. That way I don't have to write any code in my delegates or my ListViews. The only thing I had to do is, to implement my own TextInput widget, that shows the keyboard, when the cursorVisibleEvent is changed. When the keyboard becomes visible, the receiver of my VirtualKeyboard-class set to the KeyboardWindow. When the editing is finished I change the receiver back to the MainWindow and send call the sendKey() function for every letter I've written in the KeyboardWindow. That way I can also decide to disable the keyboard completely

Comment: At this moment I'm near to my projects end but I will provide a solution, when there is some space. Anyway, thank you really much!